# Sql Server Naming of columns that are very similar to table name

Tags: database, database-design

What is a good strategy for naming the columns of a table such as say Region, when the only fields are the actual region and description. Naming the column Region when the table is also called Region causes problems with ORMS etc.

**Edit**
Forgot to mention that naming standards require the use of an identity field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about RegionId or RegionName and Description?

Comment: Seems solid, are there any issues semantic, idealistic or other if you just used Name instead of RegionName?

Comment: @lee - there nothing semantically incorrect about calling it Name. That would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Region itself as and ID you still can name it RegionId, but you have to be sure that value won't be the same for other items or else it won't be a valid ID, If when you say Region you mean for example a Geographic Region then the best would be using another field to be used as ID (and primery key), like zip code or whatever unique value that applies to a Region.  Or you could use multiple fields as primary key, like country->State->Region (or any distinct order) in the Region Table or an associative Table.